# making binned boxplot in matplotlib with numpy and scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, plot

I have a 2-d array containing pairs of values and I'd like to make a boxplot of the y-values by different bins of the x-values.  I.e. if the array is:

```
my_array = array([[1, 40.5], [4.5, 60], ...]])
```

then I'd like to bin my_array[:, 0] and then for each of the bins, produce a boxplot of the corresponding my_array[:, 1] values that fall into each box.  So in the end I want the plot to contain number of bins-many box plots.

I tried the following:

```
min_x = min(my_array[:, 0])
max_x = max(my_array[:, 1])

num_bins = 3
bins = linspace(min_x, max_x, num_bins)
elts_to_bins = digitize(my_array[:, 0], bins)
```

However, this gives me values in elts_to_bins that range from 1 to 3. I thought I should get 0-based indices for the bins, and I only wanted 3 bins.  I'm assuming this is due to some trickyness with how bins are represented in linspace vs. digitize.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?  I want num_bins-many equally spaced bins, with the first bin containing the lower half of the data and the upper bin containing the upper half... i.e., I want each data point to fall into some bin, so that I can make a boxplot.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy has a [dedicated function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for creating histograms the way you need to:

```
histogram(a, bins=10, range=None, normed=False, weights=None, new=None)
```

which you can use like:

```
(hist_data, bin_edges) = histogram(my_array[:,0], weights=my_array[:,1])
```

The key point here is to use the `weights` argument: each value `a[i]` will contribute `weights[i]` to the histogram.  Example:

```
a = [0, 1]
weights = [10, 2]
```

describes 10 points at x = 0 and 2 points at x = 1.

You can set the number of bins, or the bin limits, with the `bins` argument (see the [official documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for more details).

The histogram can then be plotted with something like:

```
bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist_data)
```

If you only need to do a histogram *plot*, the similar [hist()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function can directly plot the histogram:

```
hist(my_array[:,0], weights=my_array[:,1])
```

Comment: I don't understand why "weights" is used here after reading the docs -- could you please explain?  If the point is just to assign elements to bins, I don't see why weights should play a role.

Comment: I edited the answer so as to explain in more details the role of the weights argument.  If you think that the answer is useful, please thumb it up! :)

Comment: Actually, np.histogram won't do what he needs, unfortunately. He needs the actual values that fall into each bin in order to make a boxplot for each bin. (Or that was my understanding, anyway, correct me if I'm wrong, there!)  The weights parameter just multiplies each value by each weight, so that instead of adding 1 to the count in the bin, it adds weights[i].  That's a different effect than binning one array by the values in another, and regardless, doesn't return the subset of the array that falls into each bin. (Or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding things?)

Comment: @Joe: I see what you mean.  Whatever the answer, one of our responses should be correct, so they are both useful. :)

Answer (score 8):

You're getting the 3rd bin for the maximum value in the array (I'm assuming you have a typo there, and max_x should be "max(my_array[:,0])" instead of "max(my_array[:,1])").  You can avoid this by adding 1 (or any positive number) to the last bin.

Also, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to bin one variable by another, so my example below shows that.  If you're using recarrays (which are much slower) there are also several functions in matplotlib.mlab (e.g. mlab.rec_groupby, etc) that do this sort of thing.

Anyway, in the end, you might have something like this (to bin x by the values in y, assuming x and y are the same length)

```
def bin_by(x, y, nbins=30):
    """
    Bin x by y.
    Returns the binned "x" values and the left edges of the bins
    """
    bins = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nbins+1)
    # To avoid extra bin for the max value
    bins[-1] += 1 

    indicies = np.digitize(y, bins)

    output = []
    for i in xrange(1, len(bins)):
        output.append(x[indicies==i])

    # Just return the left edges of the bins
    bins = bins[:-1]

    return output, bins
```

As a quick example:

```
In [3]: x = np.random.random((100, 2))

In [4]: binned_values, bins = bin_by(x[:,0], x[:,1], 2)

In [5]: binned_values
Out[5]: 
[array([ 0.59649575,  0.07082605,  0.7191498 ,  0.4026375 ,  0.06611863,
        0.01473529,  0.45487203,  0.39942696,  0.02342408,  0.04669615,
        0.58294003,  0.59510434,  0.76255006,  0.76685052,  0.26108928,
        0.7640156 ,  0.01771553,  0.38212975,  0.74417014,  0.38217517,
        0.73909022,  0.21068663,  0.9103707 ,  0.83556636,  0.34277006,
        0.38007865,  0.18697416,  0.64370535,  0.68292336,  0.26142583,
        0.50457354,  0.63071319,  0.87525221,  0.86509534,  0.96382375,
        0.57556343,  0.55860405,  0.36392931,  0.93638048,  0.66889756,
        0.46140831,  0.01675165,  0.15401495,  0.10813141,  0.03876953,
        0.65967335,  0.86803192,  0.94835281,  0.44950182]),
 array([ 0.9249993 ,  0.02682873,  0.89439141,  0.26415792,  0.42771144,
        0.12292614,  0.44790357,  0.64692616,  0.14871052,  0.55611472,
        0.72340179,  0.55335053,  0.07967047,  0.95725514,  0.49737279,
        0.99213794,  0.7604765 ,  0.56719713,  0.77828727,  0.77046566,
        0.15060196,  0.39199123,  0.78904624,  0.59974575,  0.6965413 ,
        0.52664095,  0.28629324,  0.21838664,  0.47305751,  0.3544522 ,
        0.57704906,  0.1023201 ,  0.76861237,  0.88862359,  0.29310836,
        0.22079126,  0.84966201,  0.9376939 ,  0.95449215,  0.10856864,
        0.86655289,  0.57835533,  0.32831162,  0.1673871 ,  0.55742108,
        0.02436965,  0.45261232,  0.31552715,  0.56666458,  0.24757898,
        0.8674747 ])]
```

Hope that helps a bit!